# C# Multiple Web Data/Stream Reader

Tags: c#

I'm trying to learn programming by myself the best I can but, seems like my code isn't as productive as it can be. I'm trying to learn by doing things that I would use on a normal occasion and I can't figure out how to properly manage it, so any information would be greatly appreciated.

I'm working on a discord bot for personal use at the moment, it works fine, the loadout time is just terrible when it comes to this part of the command. Maybe cause I'm trying to have it open, read, and close multiple databases? Or is there another explanation or method to doing this that can make it load within a faster time?

```
        string NormalExp = "0";
        string IronExp = "0";
        string HCExp = "0";
        string UIMExp = "0";

        //Normal Account
        try
        {
            WebRequest NormalScore = WebRequest.Create("https://secure.runescape.com/m=hiscore_oldschool/index_lite.ws?player=" + player);
            WebResponse NormalResponse = NormalScore.GetResponse();
            using (Stream NormalDStream = NormalResponse.GetResponseStream())
            {
                StreamReader NormalReader = new StreamReader(NormalDStream);
                string NormalResponseFromServer = NormalReader.ReadToEnd();
                var _Score = NormalResponseFromServer.Split('\n');

                var _Total = _Score[0];
                var _TotalGet = _Total.Split(',');
                var _TotalRank = _TotalGet[0];
                var _TotalLevel = _TotalGet[1];
                var _TotalExp = _TotalGet[2];

                NormalExp = _TotalExp;
            }
            NormalResponse.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }

        //Normal Ironman
        try
        {
            WebRequest IronScore = WebRequest.Create("https://secure.runescape.com/m=hiscore_oldschool_ironman/index_lite.ws?player=" + player);
            WebResponse IronResponse = IronScore.GetResponse();
            using (Stream IronDStream = IronResponse.GetResponseStream())
            {
                StreamReader IronReader = new StreamReader(IronDStream);
                string IronResponseFromServer = IronReader.ReadToEnd();
                var _Score = IronResponseFromServer.Split('\n');

                var _Total = _Score[0];
                var _TotalGet = _Total.Split(',');
                var _TotalRank = _TotalGet[0];
                var _TotalLevel = _TotalGet[1];
                var _TotalExp = _TotalGet[2];

                IronExp = _TotalExp;
            }
            IronResponse.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }

        //Hardcore Ironman
        try
        {
            WebRequest HCScore = WebRequest.Create("https://secure.runescape.com/m=hiscore_oldschool_hardcore_ironman/index_lite.ws?player=" + player);
            WebResponse HCResponse = HCScore.GetResponse();
            using (Stream HCDStream = HCResponse.GetResponseStream())
            {
                StreamReader HCReader = new StreamReader(HCDStream);
                string HCResponseFromServer = HCReader.ReadToEnd();
                var _Score = HCResponseFromServer.Split('\n');

                var _Total = _Score[0];
                var _TotalGet = _Total.Split(',');
                var _TotalRank = _TotalGet[0];
                var _TotalLevel = _TotalGet[1];
                var _TotalExp = _TotalGet[2];

                HCExp = _TotalExp;
            }
            HCResponse.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }

        //Ultimate Ironman
        try
        {
            WebRequest UIMScore = WebRequest.Create("https://secure.runescape.com/m=hiscore_oldschool_ultimate/index_lite.ws?player=" + player);
            WebResponse UIMResponse = UIMScore.GetResponse();
            using (Stream UIMDStream = UIMResponse.GetResponseStream())
            {
                StreamReader UIMReader = new StreamReader(UIMDStream);
                string UIMResponseFromServer = UIMReader.ReadToEnd();
                var _Score = UIMResponseFromServer.Split('\n');

                var _Total = _Score[0];
                var _TotalGet = _Total.Split(',');
                var _TotalRank = _TotalGet[0];
                var _TotalLevel = _TotalGet[1];
                var _TotalExp = _TotalGet[2];

                UIMExp = _TotalExp;
            }
            UIMResponse.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }

        await ReplyAsync(
                $"**Normal: ** {NormalExp}\n" +
                $"**Ironman: ** {IronExp}\n" +
                $"**Hardcore: ** {HCExp}\n" +
                $"**UIM: ** {UIMExp}");

        if (Convert.ToInt64(UIMExp) == Convert.ToInt64(NormalExp))
        {
            await ReplyAsync("Account is a UIM");
        }
        else if (Convert.ToInt64(HCExp) == Convert.ToInt64(NormalExp))
        {
            await ReplyAsync("Account is a HC");
        }
        else if (Convert.ToInt64(IronExp) == Convert.ToInt64(NormalExp) && Convert.ToInt64(IronExp) > Convert.ToInt64(UIMExp + HCExp))
        {
            if (Convert.ToInt32(UIMExp) > 1)
            {
                await ReplyAsync("Account is a ~~UIM~~ Normal Ironman");
            }
            else if (Convert.ToInt64(HCExp) > 1)
            {
                await ReplyAsync("Account is a ~~HC~~ Normal Ironman");
            }
            else
            {
                await ReplyAsync("Account is a Normal Ironman");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (Convert.ToInt64(UIMExp) > 1 && Convert.ToInt64(IronExp) > 1)
            {
                await ReplyAsync("Account is a ~~UIM~~, ~~Ironman~~, normal player.");
            }
            else if (Convert.ToInt64(HCExp) > 1 && Convert.ToInt64(IronExp) > 1)
            {
                await ReplyAsync("Account is a ~~HC~~, ~~Ironman~~, normal player.");
            }
            else if (Convert.ToInt64(IronExp) > 1 && Convert.ToInt64(HCExp) == 0 && Convert.ToInt64(UIMExp) == 0)
            {
                await ReplyAsync("Account is a ~~Ironman~~ normal player.");
            }
            else
            {
                await ReplyAsync("Account is a Normal Player");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

In general, sending requests is an expensive operation but you can improve it by changing your method.

Try to use [HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient) instead of WebRequest

and I suggest reading about Async/Sync operations